# Pandas Resample Method: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'"

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe where I would like to resample the data (currently at 15 minute resolution) to an hourly resolution and return the mean for the resampled data. Here is an example of my data:

```
        Day      Time          Timestamp     Weekday Hour   Speed (mph) Volume Weighted Speed (mph) Occupancy (%)   Volume  Flow (vph)  Factored Up Volume  Total Readings  Valid Readings  Invalid Readings    Missing Readings    Controller Error Count  Max Volume Fail Count   Max Occupancy Fail Count    Max Speed Fail Count    ZeroVolume-NonZeroSpeed Fail Count  ZeroSpeed-NonZeroVolume-NonZeroOccupancy Fail Count Max Estimated Density Fail Count
252 2022-01-03  15:00:00    01/03/2022 15:00    2.0 15.0    66.925581   66.530928   5.033333    388.0   1552.0  388.0   90  90  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
253 2022-01-03  15:15:00    01/03/2022 15:15    2.0 15.0    66.937570   65.811005   5.744444    418.0   1672.0  418.0   90  90  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
254 2022-01-03  15:30:00    01/03/2022 15:30    2.0 15.0    67.702821   67.373684   4.977778    380.0   1520.0  380.0   90  90  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
255 2022-01-03  15:45:00    01/03/2022 15:45    2.0 15.0    66.999628   66.585366   5.422222    410.0   1640.0  410.0   90  90  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
256 2022-01-03  16:00:00    01/03/2022 16:00    2.0 16.0    66.945655   66.748330   6.155556    449.0   1796.0  449.0   90  90  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I have attempted the following:

1. convert the Timestamp column to a datetime data type:

   ```
   df_el_jan_mar_wkday['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df_el_jan_mar_wkday['Timestamp'], infer_datetime_format= True)
   ```
2. Set the Timestamp column as the dataframe index:

   ```
   df_el_jan_mar_wkday.index = df_el_jan_mar_wkday['Timestamp']
   ```
3. Resample thed data and return the mean:

   `df_el_jan_mar_wkday_hourly = df_el_jan_mar_wkday.resample('H').mean()`

However, I get the following error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py:1490, in GroupBy._cython_agg_general.<locals>.array_func(values)
   1489 try:
-> 1490     result = self.grouper._cython_operation(
   1491         "aggregate",
   1492         values,
   1493         how,
   1494         axis=data.ndim - 1,
   1495         min_count=min_count,
   1496         **kwargs,
   1497     )
   1498 except NotImplementedError:
   1499     # generally if we have numeric_only=False
   1500     # and non-applicable functions
   1501     # try to python agg
   1502     # TODO: shouldn't min_count matter?

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py:959, in BaseGrouper._cython_operation(self, kind, values, how, axis, min_count, **kwargs)
    958 ngroups = self.ngroups
--> 959 return cy_op.cython_operation(
    960     values=values,
    961     axis=axis,
    962     min_count=min_count,
    963     comp_ids=ids,
    964     ngroups=ngroups,
    965     **kwargs,
    966 )

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py:657, in WrappedCythonOp.cython_operation(self, values, axis, min_count, comp_ids, ngroups, **kwargs)
    649     return self._ea_wrap_cython_operation(
    650         values,
    651         min_count=min_count,
   (...)
    654         **kwargs,
    655     )
--> 657 return self._cython_op_ndim_compat(
    658     values,
    659     min_count=min_count,
    660     ngroups=ngroups,
    661     comp_ids=comp_ids,
    662     mask=None,
    663     **kwargs,
    664 )

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py:497, in WrappedCythonOp._cython_op_ndim_compat(self, values, min_count, ngroups, comp_ids, mask, result_mask, **kwargs)
    495     return res.T
--> 497 return self._call_cython_op(
    498     values,
    499     min_count=min_count,
    500     ngroups=ngroups,
    501     comp_ids=comp_ids,
    502     mask=mask,
    503     result_mask=result_mask,
    504     **kwargs,
    505 )

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py:541, in WrappedCythonOp._call_cython_op(self, values, min_count, ngroups, comp_ids, mask, result_mask, **kwargs)
    540 out_shape = self._get_output_shape(ngroups, values)
--> 541 func = self._get_cython_function(self.kind, self.how, values.dtype, is_numeric)
    542 values = self._get_cython_vals(values)

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py:173, in WrappedCythonOp._get_cython_function(cls, kind, how, dtype, is_numeric)
    171 if "object" not in f.__signatures__:
    172     # raise NotImplementedError here rather than TypeError later
--> 173     raise NotImplementedError(
    174         f"function is not implemented for this dtype: "
    175         f"[how->{how},dtype->{dtype_str}]"
    176     )
    177 return f

NotImplementedError: function is not implemented for this dtype: [how->mean,dtype->object]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[234], line 8
      2 df_el_jan_mar_wkday.index = df_el_jan_mar_wkday['Timestamp']
      3 #df_gpl_jan_mar_wkday.index = df_gpl_jan_mar_wkday['Timestamp']
      4 # Convert time index to datetime index
      5 #df_el_jan_mar_wkday.index = pd.to_datetime(df_el_jan_mar_wkday.index.astype(str).str.replace(':', '') )
      6 #df_gpl_jan_mar_wkday.index = pd.to_datetime(df_gpl_jan_mar_wkday.index.astype(str).str.replace(':', ''))
      7 # Resample the data to the desired frequency, such as by hour
----> 8 df_el_jan_mar_wkday_hourly = df_el_jan_mar_wkday.resample('H').mean()

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py:979, in Resampler.mean(self, numeric_only, *args, **kwargs)
    977 maybe_warn_args_and_kwargs(type(self), "mean", args, kwargs)
    978 nv.validate_resampler_func("mean", args, kwargs)
--> 979 return self._downsample("mean", numeric_only=numeric_only)

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py:1297, in DatetimeIndexResampler._downsample(self, how, **kwargs)
   1293     return self.asfreq()
   1295 # we are downsampling
   1296 # we want to call the actual grouper method here
-> 1297 result = obj.groupby(self.grouper, axis=self.axis).aggregate(how, **kwargs)
   1299 return self._wrap_result(result)

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py:1271, in DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate(self, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
   1268 func = maybe_mangle_lambdas(func)
   1270 op = GroupByApply(self, func, args, kwargs)
-> 1271 result = op.agg()
   1272 if not is_dict_like(func) and result is not None:
   1273     return result

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:160, in Apply.agg(self)
    157 kwargs = self.kwargs
    159 if isinstance(arg, str):
--> 160     return self.apply_str()
    162 if is_dict_like(arg):
    163     return self.agg_dict_like()

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:496, in Apply.apply_str(self)
    494     if "axis" in arg_names:
    495         self.kwargs["axis"] = self.axis
--> 496 return self._try_aggregate_string_function(obj, f, *self.args, **self.kwargs)

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:565, in Apply._try_aggregate_string_function(self, obj, arg, *args, **kwargs)
    563 if f is not None:
    564     if callable(f):
--> 565         return f(*args, **kwargs)
    567     # people may try to aggregate on a non-callable attribute
    568     # but don't let them think they can pass args to it
    569     assert len(args) == 0

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py:1855, in GroupBy.mean(self, numeric_only, engine, engine_kwargs)
   1853     return self._numba_agg_general(sliding_mean, engine_kwargs)
   1854 else:
-> 1855     result = self._cython_agg_general(
   1856         "mean",
   1857         alt=lambda x: Series(x).mean(numeric_only=numeric_only),
   1858         numeric_only=numeric_only,
   1859     )
   1860     return result.__finalize__(self.obj, method="groupby")

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py:1507, in GroupBy._cython_agg_general(self, how, alt, numeric_only, min_count, **kwargs)
   1503         result = self._agg_py_fallback(values, ndim=data.ndim, alt=alt)
   1505     return result
-> 1507 new_mgr = data.grouped_reduce(array_func)
   1508 res = self._wrap_agged_manager(new_mgr)
   1509 out = self._wrap_aggregated_output(res)

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py:1503, in BlockManager.grouped_reduce(self, func)
   1499 if blk.is_object:
   1500     # split on object-dtype blocks bc some columns may raise
   1501     #  while others do not.
   1502     for sb in blk._split():
-> 1503         applied = sb.apply(func)
   1504         result_blocks = extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
   1505 else:

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py:329, in Block.apply(self, func, **kwargs)
    323 @final
    324 def apply(self, func, **kwargs) -> list[Block]:
    325     """
    326     apply the function to my values; return a block if we are not
    327     one
    328     """
--> 329     result = func(self.values, **kwargs)
    331     return self._split_op_result(result)

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py:1503, in GroupBy._cython_agg_general.<locals>.array_func(values)
   1490     result = self.grouper._cython_operation(
   1491         "aggregate",
   1492         values,
   (...)
   1496         **kwargs,
   1497     )
   1498 except NotImplementedError:
   1499     # generally if we have numeric_only=False
   1500     # and non-applicable functions
   1501     # try to python agg
   1502     # TODO: shouldn't min_count matter?
-> 1503     result = self._agg_py_fallback(values, ndim=data.ndim, alt=alt)
   1505 return result

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py:1457, in GroupBy._agg_py_fallback(self, values, ndim, alt)
   1452     ser = df.iloc[:, 0]
   1454 # We do not get here with UDFs, so we know that our dtype
   1455 #  should always be preserved by the implemented aggregations
   1456 # TODO: Is this exactly right; see WrappedCythonOp get_result_dtype?
-> 1457 res_values = self.grouper.agg_series(ser, alt, preserve_dtype=True)
   1459 if isinstance(values, Categorical):
   1460     # Because we only get here with known dtype-preserving
   1461     #  reductions, we cast back to Categorical.
   1462     # TODO: if we ever get "rank" working, exclude it here.
   1463     res_values = type(values)._from_sequence(res_values, dtype=values.dtype)

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py:994, in BaseGrouper.agg_series(self, obj, func, preserve_dtype)
    987 if len(obj) > 0 and not isinstance(obj._values, np.ndarray):
    988     # we can preserve a little bit more aggressively with EA dtype
    989     #  because maybe_cast_pointwise_result will do a try/except
    990     #  with _from_sequence.  NB we are assuming here that _from_sequence
    991     #  is sufficiently strict that it casts appropriately.
    992     preserve_dtype = True
--> 994 result = self._aggregate_series_pure_python(obj, func)
    996 npvalues = lib.maybe_convert_objects(result, try_float=False)
    997 if preserve_dtype:

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py:1015, in BaseGrouper._aggregate_series_pure_python(self, obj, func)
   1012 splitter = self._get_splitter(obj, axis=0)
   1014 for i, group in enumerate(splitter):
-> 1015     res = func(group)
   1016     res = libreduction.extract_result(res)
   1018     if not initialized:
   1019         # We only do this validation on the first iteration

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py:1857, in GroupBy.mean.<locals>.<lambda>(x)
   1853     return self._numba_agg_general(sliding_mean, engine_kwargs)
   1854 else:
   1855     result = self._cython_agg_general(
   1856         "mean",
-> 1857         alt=lambda x: Series(x).mean(numeric_only=numeric_only),
   1858         numeric_only=numeric_only,
   1859     )
   1860     return result.__finalize__(self.obj, method="groupby")

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:11563, in NDFrame._add_numeric_operations.<locals>.mean(self, axis, skipna, numeric_only, **kwargs)
  11546 @doc(
  11547     _num_doc,
  11548     desc="Return the mean of the values over the requested axis.",
   (...)
  11561     **kwargs,
  11562 ):
> 11563     return NDFrame.mean(self, axis, skipna, numeric_only, **kwargs)

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:11208, in NDFrame.mean(self, axis, skipna, numeric_only, **kwargs)
  11201 def mean(
  11202     self,
  11203     axis: Axis | None = 0,
   (...)
  11206     **kwargs,
  11207 ) -> Series | float:
> 11208     return self._stat_function(
  11209         "mean", nanops.nanmean, axis, skipna, numeric_only, **kwargs
  11210     )

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:11165, in NDFrame._stat_function(self, name, func, axis, skipna, numeric_only, **kwargs)
  11161     nv.validate_stat_func((), kwargs, fname=name)
  11163 validate_bool_kwarg(skipna, "skipna", none_allowed=False)
> 11165 return self._reduce(
  11166     func, name=name, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, numeric_only=numeric_only
  11167 )

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:4671, in Series._reduce(self, op, name, axis, skipna, numeric_only, filter_type, **kwds)
   4666     raise TypeError(
   4667         f"Series.{name} does not allow {kwd_name}={numeric_only} "
   4668         "with non-numeric dtypes."
   4669     )
   4670 with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
-> 4671     return op(delegate, skipna=skipna, **kwds)

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py:96, in disallow.__call__.<locals>._f(*args, **kwargs)
     94 try:
     95     with np.errstate(invalid="ignore"):
---> 96         return f(*args, **kwargs)
     97 except ValueError as e:
     98     # we want to transform an object array
     99     # ValueError message to the more typical TypeError
    100     # e.g. this is normally a disallowed function on
    101     # object arrays that contain strings
    102     if is_object_dtype(args[0]):

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py:158, in bottleneck_switch.__call__.<locals>.f(values, axis, skipna, **kwds)
    156         result = alt(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
    157 else:
--> 158     result = alt(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
    160 return result

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py:421, in _datetimelike_compat.<locals>.new_func(values, axis, skipna, mask, **kwargs)
    418 if datetimelike and mask is None:
    419     mask = isna(values)
--> 421 result = func(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, mask=mask, **kwargs)
    423 if datetimelike:
    424     result = _wrap_results(result, orig_values.dtype, fill_value=iNaT)

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py:727, in nanmean(values, axis, skipna, mask)
    724     dtype_count = dtype
    726 count = _get_counts(values.shape, mask, axis, dtype=dtype_count)
--> 727 the_sum = _ensure_numeric(values.sum(axis, dtype=dtype_sum))
    729 if axis is not None and getattr(the_sum, "ndim", False):
    730     count = cast(np.ndarray, count)

File ~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:49, in _sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where)
     47 def _sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False,
     48          initial=_NoValue, where=True):
---> 49     return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
'
```

I am sure that my index data type is datetime64[ns]. Reading further into this, it seems that the index is converted to datetime.time and not datetime.datetime which is preventing the operation of the resample method. Is that correct and how can I get past this error?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the full traceback of the exception?

Comment: The basic issue is that `mean()` requires adding up the values.  But adding times is nonsense, so Python doesn't let you do it.  What is 11:00PM plus 9:00PM?  The very question is meaningless.

Comment: Perhaps you can call `mean()` and exclude that column.

Comment: @JohnGordon I agree. My intent is to return the mean of the values for each of the volume, speed and occupancy columns. I thought that simply passing the mean would do this for me.

Comment: Using `.mean` on the DataFrame will involve using it on every column. If you want to use it on individual columns, then write that code instead. That said, an "average of datetimes" can be calculated, by the technique in the duplicate I linked (if that doesn't answer the question, then it seems more like a typo).